# CakePHP requires two page loads to validate form

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

I'm writing a page where my users can change their account email and password. Here's the controller action and the view:

```
# UsersController.php
public function edit() {
    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        if($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your account has been updated.');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'edit'));
        }

        $this->Session->setFlash('There was a problem saving your account settings. Please try again.');
    }

    // Auto populate form fields
    if(!$this->request->data) {
        $this->request->data = $this->User->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array('User.id' => $this->Auth->user('id'))
        ));
    }
}

# edit.ctp
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('currentPassword', array('between' => 'You must enter your password in order to make changes', 'type' => 'password', 'value' => '', 'autocomplete' => 'off')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('email'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('password', array('type' => 'password', 'between' => 'Must be atleast 6 characters', 'value' => '', 'autocomplete' => 'off')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('confirmPassword', array('type' => 'password', 'value' => '', 'autocomplete' => 'off')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Save changes'); ?>
```

Now, I would like to make the user enter their current password in order to make changes. In order for that to work, I need to run a validation check to make sure the password they entered in `currentPassword` matches what I have in the database. One of the validation rules in my `User` model is this:

```
'currentPassword' => array(
    'custom' => array(
        'rule' => 'validateCurrentPassword',
        'message' => 'Incorrect password. Make sure you\'re using your current password.'
    )
),
```

and the relevant function that gets called:

```
public function validateCurrentPassword($data) {
    debug($data);
    return false;
}
```

So far so good, but there's some really weird behaviour. Cake only seems to validate this field after two page loads. For example, if I enter a wrong value and press "Save changes" the page refreshes, but no validation errors pop up. If I enter another wrong value, I get the validation errors. For some reason I need to submit the form twice for validation to occur.

Can anyone work out why this is?

Comment: That is weird. So, does it display 'There was a problem saving...' the first time you submit the form? The first time you save, is the variable validationErrors set in the controller? DebugKit might help to debug this. Also, do you have any callbacks like beforeSave, afterSave, etc in the model or beforeFilter callbacks in the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this->request->is('post')` is `false` the first time you submit the form and `true` the second time you submit it. Look at the `lib/Cake/Console/Templates/default/actions/controller_actions.ctp` file and you'll see that when you bake controller actions, this is the code used for `edit` actions:

```
if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
```

If you use the above code, the first form submission will be processed (because `$this->request->is('put')` will be `true`).

Look at the `FormHelper` class's `create` method (located in `lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php`) to see when a form is considered a PUT and when it's considered a POST.

Comment: Thanks, I got tripped up because I thought Cake would default to POST (as it says in `FormHelper.php`), I explicitly set the method in the view and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax call to get the password from database. When user enters into the field next  to password field,fire an event in jquery or javascript to check if the password entered by user and the password retrieved from ajax response are same if they are not give user an alert or message to enter right password,